# How to use the enter key to submit login details

Tags: xaml, winrt-xaml

I have a basic login page,

```
    <TextBox x:Name="UsernameInput" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Username, Mode=TwoWay}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Width="400" />
    <PasswordBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Password="{Binding Password, Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Width="400"/>
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Right" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Username: " VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,15" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Style="{StaticResource SubheaderTextStyle}"/>
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Right" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Password: " VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,15" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Style="{StaticResource SubheaderTextStyle}"/>

    <Button Content="Login" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" Height="50" Width="300" Command="{Binding LoginCommand}"/>
```

How can I simulate the "Login" button being pressed if the user hits the Enter key from the password field?

Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use `KeyDown` event of `PasswordBox`.

```
<PasswordBox KeyDown="txtPassword_KeyDown"/>

private void txtPassword_KeyDown(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Windows.System.VirtualKey.Enter)
        //TODO: do login
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [KeyDown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.keydown.aspx) event in the PasswordBox -

```
<PasswordBox KeyDown="PasswordKeyDown"/>
```

Then in your c# code check if the enter key has been pressed, and log in accordingly:

```
using System.Windows.Input;

private void PasswordKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
        Login();
}
```

Comment: I get the error that KeyEventArgs does not contain a definition for 'Key'

Comment: Are you using WPF or Forms KeyEventArgs ? Make sure you are using System.Windows.Input, more info here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keyeventargs.aspx

Comment: Oh I just noticed I mistagged.  I am creating a windows 8 app with WinRT, so that's probably why it doesn't work :\

Answer (score 1):

If you want that all input fields will initiate the "Login" button when pressing Enter you can use the Button `IsDefault` property and set it to True, you can read more [HERE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.button.isdefault?view=netcore-3.1).

When set to true, if you press return while some objects in the window have focus, the code of the click event of the button will be fired automatically.

If you want that only `PasswordBox` will initiate the "Login" button you can add `keyDown` property in the xaml:

```
<PasswordBox KeyDown="Password_KeyDown"/>
```

And in the C# add:

```
private void Password_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Return)
        Login();
}
```